# traverse and printing strings in python column wise

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to print a string in Python, to get a character column - wise?

Maybe like [ [ o n ] , [ * o ] ] as below
input is given in  array or list as series of words in matrix form

on
*o
the output should come like below in column wise

1. o
2. no

Comment: what's your question? Can you revise & clarify what are your example inputs & expected outputs? python strings support slicing and indexing, if that helps, e.g.,: `'david'[0]` >> `'d'` and `'david'[-2:]` >> `'id'`, etc.

Comment: [[o n], [s o]] should print 1. os, 2. no

Comment: please see [ask] and consider adding an [mcve].

Comment: i want to print strings column - wise in python

Comment: You've already said that, and it doesn't make sense unless you give some context.

Comment: if i give input like  1. on 2. *o in list now i want out like o and no

Comment: Please avoid extended comments, and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44658939/edit) your question for clarity.

Comment: For starters: there are no actual *strings* in the question you've asked, at least not *as* you've asked it. `[[o n],[* o]]` is not valid python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

strings = ['First,', 'long second,', 'and third!']

lines = zip_longest(*strings, fillvalue=' ')
for line in lines:
    print(''.join(line))

Fla
ion
rnd
sg 
t t
,sh
 ei
 cr
 od
 n!
 d 
 ,
```

`zip_longest` lets you iterate on each string, adding spaces as `fillvalue` to the shortest ones.

`list(lines)` will be `[('F', 'l', 'a'), ('i', 'o', 'n'), ...]

We can then print each line by joining the letters in each tuple.

You can add spaces between the columns:

```
for line in lines:
    print('  '.join(line))

F  l  a
i  o  n
r  n  d
s  g   
t     t
,  s  h
   e  i
   c  r
   o  d
   n  !
   d   
   ,
```

If you don't want to print `*`, just replace them with spaces:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
strings = ['ant', '*oi', '**p']
lines = zip_longest(*strings, fillvalue=' ')


for line in lines:
    print(''.join(line).replace('*',' '))
# a    
# n o  
# t i p
```

Comment: thank you when ever there is an * it should not print that and that is end like if given  1. ant 2.  *oi 3.**p then it should print 1. a then 2. no then 3. tip

Comment: Just replace the stars with spaces, see edit.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, just have your indices arranged properly:

```
li = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
for i in range(len(li[0])):
    for j in range(len(li)):
        print(li[j][i],end='')
    print()
```

I am not sure what your `*` is doing in that list.  From the output it seems you meant it as an empty spot in the list?

Comment: thank you but rather than alphabets i want the same for words , please help me